# How to validate routes if a user is admin or not?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.8

```
//This is the middle ware
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

        if(auth()->user()->isAdmin())   //isAdmin is a function in the User model which checks if the user is admin or not
        {
            return redirect('/admin');
        } else {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

    return $next($request);
}
//I already registered this middleware in kernel as well as verifyUser

Route::middleware(['auth', 'verifyUser'])->group(function() { 

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');

Route::get('/users/profile', 'UserController@view')->name('users.view-profile');

Route::get('/users/edit_profile', 'UserController@edit')->name('users.edit-profile');
});
```

Th main problem here is it shows this error in the browser
The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling Laravel to redirect admins to `/admin`, and non-admins to `/home`.

However, you've made `/admin` and `/home` **subject** to that middleware, too, so when the user gets to `/home` it redirect them to `/home` again (and again, and again, and again, forever).

You likely need two changes:

- A new middleware, applied *only* to admin routes, that only redirects non-admins away from those routes.
- Put your home/admin logic as a one-off post-login step instead of on every pageview. See the [path customization section](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-authenticating) of the Authentication docs.